# Performance tuning aggregation query?

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am attempting to aggregate some information for a collection I have using the query below:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {$match: {survey: ObjectId("54570ff2968d6e492b0e4db7")}},
    {$unwind: "$answers"},
    {$unwind: "$answers.values"},
    {$project: {q: "$answers.question", l: "$answers.values.label"}},
    {$group:{
            _id: "$l",
            total: {$sum: 1},
            question: {$first: "$q"}
        }
    }]
    ,
    {
        allowDiskUse: true,
    }
);
```

Sample data can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/0MNbW8Q5).

When I aggregate relatively small amounts of data the performance is fine.  When I aggregate larger amounts of data (20,000 documents) i'm seeing runtimes of about 3.5 seconds, and when I run it against very large amounts of data (1,000,000 documents) I see runtimes of 1-2 minutes.

I have several indexes on `myCollection` but I think the only one that applies to the above query is `{survey: 1, created: 1}`

When I include the explain for the above query it shows `BTreeCursor` under `stages.$cursor.plan.cursor` which I believe means the query is using necessary indexes ([full explain available here](http://pastebin.com/gxX2D92a)).

I read through [MongoDB's optimization guidelines](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) and it seems like I'm already using the applicable ones.

Can anyone suggest anything to help improve the performance of the above query considering what I have already tried?  Is there anything obvious that I am missing in my attempts to speed this guy up?

UPDATE - including sample data:

```
{
   email: "test@test.com,
  answers:[
    {  
       question: ObjectId("54571089968d6e492b10133d"),
       values: [{label: "option 1", value: true}]
    }
  ]
},
{
  email: "another@test.com,
   answers:[
     {  
        question: ObjectId("54571089968d6e492b10133d"),
        values: [{label: "option 1", value: true}]
     }
   ]
},
,
{
   email: "one@more.com,
  answers:[
    {  
       question: ObjectId("54571089968d6e492b10133d"),
       values: [
                 {label: "option 2", value: true},
                 {label: "option 1", value: true}
               ]
    }
  ]
}
```

UPDATE 2 - including the explain:

```
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "survey" : ObjectId("54570ff2968d6e492b0e4db7")
                },
                "fields" : {
                    "answers" : 1,
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "plan" : {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "survey" : [
                            [
                                ObjectId("54570ff2968d6e492b0e4db7"),
                                ObjectId("54570ff2968d6e492b0e4db7")
                            ]
                        ],
                        "created" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "allPlans" : [
                        {
                            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "scanAndOrder" : false,
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "survey" : [
                                    [
                                        ObjectId("54570ff2968d6e492b0e4db7"),
                                        ObjectId("54570ff2968d6e492b0e4db7")
                                    ]
                                ],
                                "created" : [
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "$minElement" : 1
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$maxElement" : 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "answers" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : "$answers"
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : "$answers.values"
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "q" : "$answers.question",
                "l" : "$answers.values.label"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$l",
                "total" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                },
                "question" : {
                    "$first" : "$q"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample document, the link may be blocked in many places, such as mine :(.

Comment: `unwind` is the killer here, can you try adding `{$project:{"answers":1}}`, just after the initial match stage? And can you update the question with what index the optimizer is using? Does your collection have an index on the `survey` field alone?

Comment: @BatScream - Adding the extra project leave the run time basically the same, maybe a 1 second difference.  How would I determine which index is used?  The `explain` didn't seem to include any index names.  I don't have an index that is only on the `survey` field, just the compound index.

Comment: The index used will be present in the  "cursor" attribute of the `explain()` o/p object.  Also can you note what is the number against `nscannedObjects` attribute?

Comment: @BatScream - So i went ahead and updated the question to include the `explain` from my query.  I can't see anything about which index it is using.  Is this because it's the explain from an `aggregate` rather than a normal query?

Comment: It is using the compound index on the `created` field and the `survey` fields. The `indexbounds` for the `match` stage shows this. That is the only index it has evaluated, the `allplans` field tells that. Yes the explain plan has been introduced in 2.6 for aggregation.

Comment: You Remove the **`$project`** entirely since is really isn't doing anything. The pipeline will omit the fields not used automatically ( See [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization) ). Re-shaping documents does more harm than good. Field selection should generally be optimized out as covered. But really this would seem to come down to the memory cap on aggregation and "disk use" while good will of course slow down IO. Sharding will speed this and moderns versions can run the whole pipeline without gather

Comment: @NeilLunn - thanks for the info.  Could you go into more detail as to what you mean by, "...run the whole pipeline without gather"?  Also - would moving the `answers` array to it's own collection speed things up because I would no longer need to use `aggregate` with `unwind`?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match with the pipeline - where's the `survey` field? Is that field indexed? How many documents are there per value of `survey`? How long are the `answers` and `answer.values` array generally?